Github not showing up on VS Code macOS Sonoma
I've been trying to install git on macOS to use within Visual Studio Code, I've attempted to install it and when I go to VS Code > Source Control - Nothing shows up where I can clone a repository. When I hit CMD + SHIFT + P and type git, nothing shows up.
I've tried installing git via cmd line with brew as stated by the creators of git. I've done that, I've set the $PATH variable as needed. This is my path in on Mac
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

I've attempted to update my visual studio code settings.json which is below
json{
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "git.path": "/usr/bin/git",
    "git.enabled": true
}

I've also tried updating the setting.json to
json{
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "git.path": "/opt/homebrew/bin",
    "git.enabled": true
}

Running "git --version" in terminal returns this "git version 2.47.1"
"which git" returns this "/opt/homebrew/bin/git" - I've also updated settings.json git.path to reflect this and git still doesn't show up in visual studio code.
I've updated Xcode as needed and the command line tools as well.
I'm stuck on what to try next and where to go. Maybe it's something small I'm missing but I can't figure this out.
